# Vector layer no longer editable in QGIS?

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3, editing

This problem was previously mentioned for QGIS 2.16 but I was hoping that QGIS 3.16.5 will not have the same problem. Somehow a vector shapefile gets into a state where it is not possible to edit the layer (the pencil is grey in the attribute table).
I was adding lines to a vector layer and saved the changes but nothing was saved (all changes were lost) and now the layer is not editable. Restarting QGIS does not help. Removing the layer and adding it again does not help.
I previously I had the same problem and I had to create a new vector layer.

Is it a bug or a mistake on my side?

The problem shapefile can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/2w52aurd9tbi2hr/Uneditable%20layer.zip?dl=0

Comment: When I open the shapefile, it's empty - so difficult to say what happened to it. When and how did it happen that it was not working any more? I guess you are aware of the limitations of Shapefiles (as regarding fieldname length etc.)? Consider using Geopackage instead - it's the new default format since QGIS 3.0 and should you give less trouble.

Comment: have no issues editing your line shapefile in UTM 34S in QGIS 3.18.1 - there was no attributes (even FID was missing).

Comment: Thanks Babel for the Geopackage suggestion. Maybe Shapefiles are not the most reliable format.